# Best way to find a whitespace-delimited word in a CString

Tags: c++, mfc

example: "`select * from somewhere where x = 1`"

I want to find the whitespace-delimited "`where`", but not the "`where`" within "`somewhere`". In the example "where" is delimited by spaces, but it could be carriage returns, tabs etc.

Note: I know regex would make it easy to do (the regex equivalent would be "`\bwhere\b`"), but I don't want to add a regex library to my project just to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to use the pure MFC method of string manipulation, then this should work:

```
CString strSql = _T("select * from somewhere where x = 1");

int nTokenPos = 0;
CString strToken = strSql.Tokenize(_T(" \r\n\t"), nTokenPos);

while (!strToken.IsEmpty())
{
    if (strToken.Trim().CompareNoCase(_T("where")) == 0)
        return TRUE; // found
    strToken = strSql.Tokenize(_T(" \r\n\t"), nTokenPos);
}

return FALSE; // not found
```

Comment: I like this answer. It uses pure MFC, which I prefer, and also enables to do case insensitive searches. sbi's and JIa3ep's answers are also pretty good, though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the first thing about MFC and `CString`, but in plain C++ I'd stuff that string into an `std::istringstream` and read from that into a string:

```
std::istringstream iss("select * from somewhere where x = 1");
std::string word;
do {
  iss >> word;
  if( !iss ) throw "blah blah!";
} while( word != "where" );
```

I suppose `CString` does have stream operators overloaded with the appropriate semantics, but, as I said, I don't know it.

Comment: The extraction requires an ostream, and will read from any ostreambuf. You'd need an ostreambuf over CString to do this.

Comment: @MSalters: Ah, `istream` -- _that_ I understand. Anyway, I wouldn't know whether there's any stream buffers for `CString`. I never used MFC.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty fast and doesn't need to construct heavy `istringstream` objects.

```
CString str = L"select * from somewhere where x = 1";
CString to_find = L"where";
int i =0;
while ( i < str.GetLength() ) {
    i = str.Find(to_find, i);
    if ( i == -1 ) break;
    if ( (i == 0 || !isalpha(str[i-1])) && (i == str.GetLength()-to_find.GetLength() || !isalpha(str[i+to_find.GetLength()])) ) break;
    i+=to_find.GetLength();
}
if ( i >= 0 && i < str.GetLength() ) // found
else // not found
```

Comment: this one actually enables to search for more complex expressions like "GROUP BY"

Comment: Yes, my solution is universal and doesn't require additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 with Feature Pack you already have [std::tr1::regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx) in C++.

Answer (score -1):

Well, regex is the correct answer. If you don't want to include regex, you will have to try and implement a bit of regex yourself and search for " where ".

Your only other option I guess would be to search for "where", then check the character before and after the match to see if they are whitespace characters.