# Split functionality for MFC Cstring Class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to Split a `CString` object by delimeter in vc++?

For example I have a `string` value

> "one+two+three+four"

into a `CString` varable.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177276/best-way-to-find-a-whitespace-delimited-word-in-a-cstring):

```
CString str = _T("one+two+three+four");

int nTokenPos = 0;
CString strToken = str.Tokenize(_T("+"), nTokenPos);

while (!strToken.IsEmpty())
{
    // do something with strToken
    // ....
    strToken = str.Tokenize(_T("+"), nTokenPos);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Tokenize is not supported in VC6 MFC, But supported in ATL

Comment: You should probably add that requirement to the question.

Comment: [The docs for CStringT::Tokenize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4ftfkd2.aspx) say that the function skips leading delimiters, so if you truly want to split a string and not ignore empty substrings, then I would say that you can't use `Tokenize()`. For instance, "+one+two+three+four" would not yield the expected result of 5 substrings.

Answer (score 25):

```
CString sInput="one+two+three";
CString sToken=_T("");
int i = 0; // substring index to extract
while (AfxExtractSubString(sToken, sInput, i,'+'))
{   
   //.. 
   //work with sToken
   //..
   i++;
}
```

[`AfxExtractSubString` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991543.aspx).

Comment: That's one problem with crappy OO and poor APIs - functions all over the place :) Good find.

Comment: You can answer your own question. It's in the FAQ.

Comment: I would change the comma separator to a plus-sign, or the example won't work.

Comment: Thanks, but does this approach allow for empty tokens? Eg: "one++three+four"

Answer (score 12):

```
int i = 0;
CStringArray saItems;
for(CString sItem = sFrom.Tokenize(" ",i); i >= 0; sItem = sFrom.Tokenize(" ",i))
{
    saItems.Add( sItem );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In VC6, where `CString` does not have a Tokenize method, you can defer to the [`strtok`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us?query=strtok) function and it's friends.

```
#include <tchar.h>

// ...

CString cstr = _T("one+two+three+four");
TCHAR * str = (LPCTSTR)cstr;
TCHAR * pch = _tcstok (str,_T("+"));
while (pch != NULL)
{
  // do something with token in pch
  // 
  pch = _tcstok (NULL, _T("+"));
}

// ...
```

Comment: `TCHAR * str = (LPCTSTR)cstr` will throw a compiler error as `a value of type "LPCTSTR" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "TCHAR *"`. You should use `TCHAR * str = cstr.GetBuffer();`