# Visual C++ is there something like explode for Strings?

Tags: visual-c++, explode, cstring

I have a CString that I'd like to break up much the way a php explode() would do, I haven't seen anything like this in C++.  Does anybody have an easy way to split up a string into substrings given the separator character?

Comment: Most people call that `Split`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split functionality for MFC Cstring Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147198/split-functionality-for-mfc-cstring-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent, but the Tokenize method is similar, and can be used as the basis of function to work like PHP's explode.